# Writing text using ncurses

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple text editor using ncurses so that the user can edit a line but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

This is what I have so far

```
void initWindow(){

    int posx = 0, posy = 0, ncol = 45, pos = 0;;
    int ch;
    char string[ncol];
    memset(string, '*', ncol);



    while(1){

        initscr();
        clear();
        noecho();
        cbreak();
        keypad(stdscr, TRUE);


        mvprintw(0,0, "%s", string);
        move(0, pos);
        ch = getch();

        switch(ch){

            case KEY_RIGHT:
                if(pos < ncol)
                    pos++;

                break;

            case KEY_LEFT:
                if(pos > 0)
                  pos--;

                break;

            case KEY_DC:
                memmove(&string[pos], &string[pos + 1], strlen(string));
                break;

            case KEY_BACKSPACE:

                if(pos > 0 && pos < ncol){
                    memmove(&string[pos-1], &string[pos], strlen(string));  
                    move(0,pos--);
                }
                break;

            case 10:
                clear(); /*ENTER*/
                mvprintw(0,0,"Linha: %s\n", string);

                getch();
                return;

            case 27:
                clear(); //ESCAPE
                return;

            default:

                if(ch > 31 && ch < 127 && string[ncol - 1] == '\0' && pos < ncol && pos > 0){
                memmove(&string[pos+1], &string[pos], ncol -pos);
                string[pos] = ch;
                pos++;
                }
                break;    
        }
    }

}
```

It ouputs this

> *********************************************~[B

And I can't even write anything, although the backspace and delete buttons work.

I would like to know how can I make it so that I can write a simple text?

And can someone explain why does it output that junk characters at the end of the output?

Thanks

EDIT: `main` function call this function and here are the #includes as requested

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>
```

EDIT2: Still haven't figured this out, anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It’ll be easier to help you if you can narrow down your question to something more specific than *it doesn’t work*, and if you can provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't really know how can I be more explicit.. The code I made is there if anyone wants to reproduce and the question is there too

Comment: @F.Dinis: the code you've posted does not compile -- there's no `main`, no `#include` directives...

Comment: One obvious problem -- you're calling `initscr` in your loop.  `initscr` should be called ONCE when the program starts...

Comment: @ChrisDodd `main` just calls this function and the includes are the same as when a new project is created but i can add them here

Comment: @ChrisDodd I've put the `initscr`outside of the loop, dumb move on my part but it still didn't change anything

Comment: The point of an MCVE is that someone can jsut copy-paste your code and compile it with no further editing.  Without that most people will not try to reconstruct what you are doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One pointer, you are using `initscr()` in the while loop.  This means you're re-initializing and discovering the terminal type each pass of the loop.  You should do this once.

Also, `initscr()` does an initial clear before any further processing, so the `clear()` after `initscr()` is not needed.

Perhaps your terminal output will improve if you avoid excessively re-initializing the system.

Comment: I took out the `clear()`part and the problem still stands.
Although now when i delete some asterisks it adds this at the end of the line
`*************************kHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH`

Comment: put the initscr() out of the loop.  You are only supposed to run initscr() once for the program, not once per pass through your loop

Comment: I did, same result still

Comment: That's because your program has other errors in it.

Answer (score -1):

Couple obvious problems:

- `initscr` being called multiple times in the loop; it only needs to be called once
- `string` is not NUL terminated, so you're probably seeing garbage after the end of it.
- `memove` calls also do the wrong thing with NUL terminator on the string even if it was there...

Comment: I fixed the first one, how can I fix the rest?